# Does JMeter Aggregate Report includes WarmUp and CoolDown samples?

Tags: jmeter

I am using Ultimate Thread group which includes a warmup time of 5 mins and cool down of 5 mins.  Does JMeter Aggregate Report includes requests executed during WarmUp and CoolDown  ?. If so is there any way to exclude during test run. In my opinion, including response during warmup will have an effect to overall Avg or 90% time. can anyone help in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter's Aggregate Report listener includes **everything** which is in its [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules).

If you want to exclude ramp-up and ramp-down periods you have the following options:

1. Manually inspect [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles?src=contextnavpagetreemode) and delete sample results for first and last 5 minutes, the first column contains timestamps in milliseconds since start of [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) so if you add `300000` to the first sampler start time and subtract `300000` from the last sampler start time the remaining results will be the ones you're looking for
2. You can use [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line) which provides `--start-offset` and `--end-offset` parameters allowing to specify the custom range like:

   ```
   JMeterPluginsCMD --generate-csv aggregate-report.csv --input-jtl /path/to/your/test/result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
   ```

   this way you will get CSV representation of the Aggregate Report table
3. There is [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) which can "cut" ramp-up and ramp-down periods from the .jtl results file

   ```
   FilterResults --output-file filtered.csv --input-file /path/to/your/test/result.jtl --start-offset 300 --end-offset 300
   ```

   this way you will get .jtl file with removed first and last 5 minutes, you can open it in the Aggregate Report listener or generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of it